# Is Samsung still not persisting foreground services?

Tags: android, persistence, samsung-mobile, foreground-service

I check back about every six months to ask this question.  Have yet to get an answer.  Some time ago Samsung stopped persisting foreground services yielding hundreds if not thousands of Android apps useless. I had to mothball all my apps and give up Android development because of this.

More info about this can be found at https://dontkillmyapp.com/samsung

Is anything being done about this disaster?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it still does the same.

Even adding the apps to the suggested exclusion lists and doing the suggested actions on the website, your apps can get killed sometimes. I've missed quite a few reminders from my to-do app because of that.

Additionally, it's not only Samsung that does this, other manufacturers do it too, albeit not as aggressively.